# Kubernetes: how to replace to the 3 Intermediate CAs when they are expired

Tags: certificate

I am using Kubeadm to setup Kubernetes HA cluster, the default period of validity of 3 Intermediate CAs is 10 years; But how to replace those 3 intermediate CAs ten years later, I have no idea about it